# Select appointments for a specific date for a specific staff member

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net

I am having a bit of trouble writing an SQL statement. Here is my table structure:

appointment:

```
| id | tattooId | date | time | length |

tattoo:

| id | customerID | staffID | description |
```

customer:

```
| id | name | email| address|
```

staff:

```
| id | name| surname| email|
```

I need to fill a list box with appointments, but I want to use appointments for a specific date and a specific staff member. For example, if I picked date 10/03/2015 and staff member "Bob" I need to pull all appointments on that date which correlate to Bob.

> `SQLCommand.CommandText = "SELECT*FROM appointment" & _
>                       " JOIN tattoo ON Appointment.TattooID=tattoo.ID" & _
>                       " JOIN staff ON tattoo.StaffID='staff.ID'" & _
>                       " WHERE appointment.Date='2015-02-06'" & _
>                       " AND staff.staffname='" & _staff.Firstname & "';"`

so ive used this and it doesnt come up with any Syntax errors but its not reading? ive messed arround and tryed some selects but it doesnt pull anything.

the exact data im trying to get is

```
appointment.Time 
appointment.Length
appointment.Cost
Customer.name
```

sorry forgot about the customer
but would i just

```
JOIN Customer ON tattoo.CustomerID='Customer.ID'
```

Comment: I think you've got a StaffTable as well? Or is "BOB" a StaffID in TattoTable?

Comment: Why do you have `staff.id` in single quotes in the third line? It should be `tattoo.StaffID = Staff.ID` with no quotes. The same thing when you join the customer table. `Tattoo.ID` should be compared to `Customer.ID` not `'Customer.ID'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by joining the two tables on the tattooID column, and simply filter on the date in appointment table and the staffID in the tattoo table. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM appointment a
JOIN tattoo t ON t.id = a.tattooID
WHERE a.date = '2015-10-03' AND t.staffID = @bobID;
```

You don't have a `staffName` column anywhere in your tables, but I suspect you'll be able to get that information and filter for bob appropriately.

**EDIT**

To get the staff information too, just add another join:

```
SELECT *
FROM appointment a
JOIN tattoo t ON t.id = a.tattooID
JOIN staff s ON s.id = t.staffID
WHERE a.date = '2015-10-03' AND s.name = 'Bob';
```

Comment: I have staff name in my staff table but its asociated with The tattoo table

Comment: @notme61 okay, I have added an example.

Comment: doesnt seem to return a value

Answer (score 1):

Assuming StaffTable containing ID and Name:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM AppointmentTable a
JOIN TattooTable t ON a.TattooID = t.ID
JOIN StaffTable s ON t.StaffID = s.ID
WHERE a.Date = '2015-03-10'
AND s.Name = 'BOB'
```